# Paint method not working on full screen - Java

Tags: java, swing, screen, fullscreen, paint

I am trying to create a full screen with a paint method. I want "This is the day" in pink with a blue background to show up. The problem is, is that when I run my program, It shows up with what I painted on my screen with my toolbar and applications instead of showing up a blue background with "This is the day" in the middle in pink. Some code is below.

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    DisplayMode dm1 =
        new DisplayMode(800, 600, 16, DisplayMode.REFRESH_RATE_UNKNOWN);
    RunScreen runProgram = new RunScreen();
    runProgram.run(dm1);
}

public void run(DisplayMode dm)
{
    getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    setForeground(Color.PINK);

    setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 24));

    FullScreen s = new FullScreen();
    try
    {
        s.setFullScreen(dm, this);

        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }

    }
    finally
    {
        s.restoreScreen();
    }

}

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g)
{

    g.drawString("This is the day", 200, 200);

}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: To EveryoneReadingThis - shall I put my `FullScreen` class on?

Comment: *"To EveryoneReadingThis"*  I was the only one notified, and I (already) advised:  *For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).*  Follow the link, read..

Comment: @AndrewThompson I just had a dig through my short stack overflow history, and it turns out I was 11 when I posted that question!!! I'm so sorry, please excuse my stupidity.

Comment: 2013? Wow, time flies, no? A few years ago I even updated that comment to:- For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). - glad you got the problem sorted. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work just fine...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration;
import java.awt.GraphicsDevice;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestFullScreen {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestFullScreen();
    }

    public TestFullScreen() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.setUndecorated(true);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                GraphicsDevice device = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice();
                device.setFullScreenWindow(frame);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g); 
            String text = "Hello";
            FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();
            int x = (getWidth() - fm.stringWidth(text)) / 2;
            int y = ((getHeight() - fm.getHeight()) / 2) + fm.getAscent();
            g.drawString(text, x, y);
        }        
    }    
}
```

Beware, the "window" that you request to be made into a full screen window may not be the actually window used by the system.

You should avoid overriding `paint` and use `paintComponent` instead.  You should also avoid overriding `paint` of top level containers (like `JFrame`).

Check out [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for more details...

Answer (score 2):

```
Thread.sleep(5000);
```

Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread) - the GUI will 'freeze' when that happens. Instead of calling `Thread.sleep(n)` implement a Swing `Timer` for repeating tasks or a `SwingWorker` for long running tasks.  See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

Comment: When I run the program, it overrides paint itself madprogrammer

Comment: @SlickJava Hint: use @ to refer to someone

Comment: @MadProgrammer when I run the program, eclipse automatically formats the code and places an overrides the paint method.

Comment: You are talking about the `@Overrides` **notation,** whereas @MadProgrammer is referring to the very fact you put `public void paint(..` in the 1st place.  **Don't do that!**  instead add a `JPanel` and do custom painting in `public void paintComponent(..`

Comment: I did it with blocking the EDT.

Answer (score 1):

To hide toolbar and etc. Use `setUndecorated`

```
runProgram.setUndecorated(true);
runProgram.run(dm1);
```

To show up a blue background with "This is the day" in the middle in pink, set the color in `paint` (or `paintComponent`)

```
g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
g.setColor(Color.PINK);
g.drawString("This is the day", 200, 200);
```

Second, you **shouldn't** involve with GUI out of the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread). You should do those thing like this:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 24));
    }
});
```

Third, you **shouldn't** overrides `paint` of top level containers. (I don't mean the `@Override` notation). You should do as [Andrew Thompson mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16632768/paint-method-not-working-on-full-screen-java/16632943?noredirect=1#comment23918817_16632834):

Comment: Ok... It works, but I want just `g.drawString()` method inside because I fiddled around and did `g.drawRect(20,20,getWidth(),getHeight())` and it turned out to be a rectangle filled with blue. I want it specially full screen.

Comment: @SlickJava I wrote `0`, not `20`. And what do you mean by *specially full screen*? Isn't screen a rectangle?

Comment: Yes, I fiddled around with `0` and `20` and specially full screen means something inside this: `window.setUndecorated(true);
        window.setResizable(false);
        vc.setFullScreenWindow(window);` PS. Thanks for the @ sign! That helped a lot

Comment: "Third, you shouldn't overrides paint of top level containers. (I don't mean the @Override notation). You should do as Andrew Thompson mentioned:" Oh.

Answer (score 0):

> Repaint method is not entered when the frame is full screen. So this way is useful for repainting for swing JFrame.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    if (getExtendedState() == 6) {//6 full-screen, 0 normal, -1 minimized
        repaint();
    } else {
        repaint();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please correct your answer, it says nothing. A couple of hints: a) remove auto-generated comments b) expand on that conditional statement, which is useless